# How to print name/value of xml elements and it childs using php SimpleXML?

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

I have XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<bikes>
<bike>
    <model>First</model>
    <speedNumber>4</speedNumber>
    <sizes>100</sizes>
    <amount>100</amount>
</bike>
<bike>
    <model>Second</model>
    <speedNumber>3</speedNumber>
    <sizes>300</sizes>
    <amount>150</amount>
</bike>
<bike>
    <model>Third</model>
    <speedNumber>4</speedNumber>
    <sizes>300</sizes>
    <amount>300</amount>
</bike>
</bikes>
```

I read it using SimpleXML. 
How can I print info for all tags such as

```
bike: model=First , speedNumber=4 ..
```

My code:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("bike.xml") or die('Cannot load file');
foreach($xml->children() as $bikes) {
    echo $bikes->getName()." : ";
    echo $bikes->model . " ";
    echo $bikes->speedNumber . " ";
    echo $bikes->sizes . "";
    echo $bikes->amount . "<br>";
}
```

Now I print bike:

```
First 4 100 100 bike: Second 3 300 150
```

How can I print

```
bike: model=First speedNumber=4 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select childs of `$bikes` using `$bikes->children()` and loop through them. In foreach loop, generate target string.

```
foreach ($xml->children() as $bikes) {
    echo $bikes->getName()." : ";
    foreach ($bikes->children() as $childs){
        echo $childs->getName()."=".$childs ." ";
    }   
    echo "<br>";
}
```

See result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/uV79b)